# Why doesn't process node size matter for MCUs?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor

In the processor industry, everyone's goal is to race to the smallest node size possible since a decreased node size allows for better power efficiency, performance, and processor density.

However, it seems like no one cares about the node size of MCUs. It's hardly ever publicized as a device specification, and it doesn't seem like the same scaling race exists for MCUs. Why is this?

Comment: Why do you think the race does not exist? Also if current MCUs are already good enought for what they must do, why would there be need to make them more expensive with smaller processes?

Comment: Devices with internal flash are limited to what geometry is used due to the flash memory. Many newer microcontrollers use external flash to escape this problem. Sram scales easily, so these devices will usually have large sram so that you can copy the code from external flash into the sram for execution.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly cost and application.

Do you know how expensive the 7 to 14nm processes are? I mean I also don't, because NDAs and so on, but estimates give figures in the order of magnitude of smaller countries' GDP! A stm32f107 for example used to cost something like 3€, now compare that to the couple of hundreds of $$ you pay for the i7s and Ryzen 9s etc. You just don't have any margin to work with to recover your engineering costs.

Now lets look at the applications: A huge reason to pick an MCU is just "that'll do". (The other big ones are cost!!! power and special peripheries). I'm willing to bet the use case for a not insignificant number of MCUs is: React to a button, read a sensor or two and switch a couple of LEDs. 72MHz is even overkill for that. Now why would anyone pay a couple of hundreds of millions to a few billion to shrink that from 180nm (?) to 10nm. And you don't even gain a whole lot, you might be able to shrink the die to like half a square millimeter but you still have to use the same package because you have to fit your IO pins somewhere. We already touched on performance, if your MCU running at 72MHz is sufficient, why would I need transistors with a native switching frequency of somewhere around 10GHz?

Also the "better power efficiency" is a bit of a double edged sword. Yes, you get better dynamic power consumption, but leakage currents will more than kill those gains (remedied by just turning off whole portions, i.e. clock trees and even whole cores, of a chip in modern CPUs). And since dynamic power is a function of gate capacitance C and switching frequency f, the large C just doesn't matter because your f is so low. What you DO gain from using nodes above ~90-65nm is a LOT less leakage current. Like a LOT! I read a paper where they analyzed this. I don't remember the details, but the TLDR was something like this: above 90nm you could switch almost all transistors at the same time close to their maximum frequency. At ~14nm, even when reducing the speed to ~3GHz, you could switch less than a percent of all transistors in the die at the same time. So by using 180nm you can just go "leakage? don't care lol".

Then there are secondary reasons like yield etc. The larger process nodes have been around a while now and are pretty bulletproof and a lot easier to work with. Chances of getting it first-time-right are a lot higher with older processes than the cutting edge stuff where you might have to do multiple iterations, which brings us back to cost.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Colin's answer, MCU tend to have long product life cycle - 10,20 and even 30 (Motorola CPU32 parts) years of production. Masks are expensive, and if there is no justification for smaller feature size, no one will buy new masks.
On the other hand, power consumption generally goes down with feature size, so ultra-low power devices benefit from modern processes.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of reasons, many already covered.

Another reason is that microcontrollers have on-board flash memory in the vast majority of cases.

That is NOR flash which reached its feature size limit at about 65nm (the reasons have to do with much smaller features having excessive leakage via quantum tunnelling, which is precisely how floating gate flash is programmed).

There is no point in using a smaller node (or worse, mixed nodes) and driving up the price significantly.

Typically a modern MCU can run on what it took for a *single ECL gate* (25mW per gate) even in a fairly complex solution (although some of that is down to very good power management features). Low power is what MCU makers are striving for (think IIot, IoT) and the process nodes reflect that along with low cost.

Most MCUs (even the most advanced) still come in at under £10 in small quantities, and some are sub-dollar in quantity.

So there are technical and cost reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Many things.  In part:

- Fine nodes are expensive; using finer than necessary (given expected chip complexity and desired packaging size) raises part cost.
- Silicon is relatively cheap; it's what you do with it that costs so much.  Using very mature and competitive ~100nm processes means less cost (again, given the complexity and size requirements are met), and also potentially more sources to fab your parts.
- Embedded products typically work with higher voltages, which may be a consideration.  For fine process nodes, even 3.3V might be considered "high".  5V devices are still abundant, and 20V+ or even HVIC processes may be desirable (for more specialized MCUs bordering on ASICs, such as targeting PMIC and motor control).
- As finer processes mature, the price point may shift over time.

Just from my limited perspective on AVR products, I've seen the family move from 5V process (classics, ATmega and earlier) to 3.3V (XMEGA, mega0) to hybrid (AVR-Dx).

AVR-Dx is not well described on this matter, so I may be assuming some things here, but the datasheets do refer to an internal voltage regulator.  This implies a low voltage (probably 1.2-1.8V) core section, interfaced to a 5V-capable IO section.  In contrast to some chips that require a large external capacitor for this regulator, it seems they've integrated that, or optimized out the requirement entirely; the feature is almost completely transparent, and you hardly need to know it's there at all.  This in part explains the independence of clock speed with respect to supply voltage, and the relatively high complexity in smaller chip sizes (e.g. QFN-32).

It's noteworthy that AVR clock speeds have not increased appreciably across families, probably by a combination of lack of requirements (if you need a 160MHz+ CPU, get an ARM or etc.!) and probably architectural unsuitability (perhaps AVR has lots of propagation delays to achieve its mostly-single-cycle instruction timing; contrast to others that integrate pipelining and caching).  Also noteworthy that Flash timing does not improve much with feature size, so any device running above 60MHz or so will still be limited by the same worst-case response time.

Other families of course have used this architecture for a long time (i.e., 3.3 or 5V I/O with a low voltage core) — but because they have to (say to offer a 200MHz core at 3.3V IO), and it's only more recently that it's been applied to slower products such as these.

Answer (score 1):

Node size tends to be important when you want to pack in very large numbers of cores, and in particular the matching caches.

For mainline desktop/server CPUs the desired specs requires very, very large number of transistors, and to be thermally viable very low power per gate. Just look at the size of the L3 cache on the latest Intel and AMD chips, the number of cores, and the total power consumption. This is only really possible with the very smallest geometries.

With MCU, the gate count is much smaller, so geometry is very rarely an issue.